# How to save form contents using JavaScript when clicking the Save as Draft button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form, it has a regular Checkout button and a Save as Draft. When a user clicks Save as Draft button I want the information that user as  written to stay in the fields. When a user logs back in, clicks on the form through his/her profile, he can see the information that he had filled out.  So far this is what I have done with the javascript.

Button Code:

```
<input  class="save-button" type="button" onclick="return saveForm();" value="Save for later" />
```

.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save-button").click(function(){
        form.saveForm();
});
```

I don't want the information to be submitted into the database until the user has clicked Checkout (unless it is inevitable). But I am not sure what kind of script should I write to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Saving it to the database is fine. You just need a column on the database row that lets you mark it as a draft. You can then use the data to repopulate the form when the draft is edited.